# The system cannot find the file specified Exception in Process Start (tscon.exe)

Tags: c#, process

I am getting "The system cannot find the file specified Exception" in Process.Start on tscon

Working:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe", "temp.txt"));
```

Not Working:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe", @"0 /dest:console"));
```

I need the tscon.exe.
why am i getting this error?

**EDIT:**

1. Verified that tscon.exe is indeed in `c:\Windows\System32` folder.
2. I am running VS in administrator mode

is there some hardening on that file? not being able to understand this...

Comment: Are you sure `tscon.exe` is in system32 directory? Are you sure you can access that software with your credentials?

Comment: try running your compiled exe using the "run as admin.." to see if it's not permissions.

Comment: can only confirm the OP statements. Tried also with     `ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();`  `pi.FileName = "cmd";` `pi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\windows\System32";` `pi.Arguments = "@/k \"tscon.exe 0 /dest:console\"";` and the results are the same. However if I try from a manually open command prompt it works.

Comment: asking again, just to be sure, did you check that `tscon.exe` is located in `c:\Windows\System32\` ? I'm asking cause I don't have it at that location in my Windows 7 x64 Home Edition. I did found it in: `C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..es-commandlinetools_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_42d65ed50fa3c682` though.

Comment: @RăzvanPanda if you open a command prompt with admin rights (run as administrator) you will see the file.

Comment: @Steve: I tried that and it is still not there. Also enabled to show hidden files and protected operating system files from folder options and it still doesn't appear to be there. I think maybe it is not installed as default on home edition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh well, this thing has really got my attention.
I have finally managed to start the tscon.exe from Process.Start.
You need to pass your "admin" account info, otherwise you get the 'File not found' error.

Do in this way

```
ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
pi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\windows\System32"; //Not really needed
pi.FileName = "tscon.exe";
pi.Arguments = "0 /dest:console";
pi.UserName = "steve";
System.Security.SecureString s = new System.Security.SecureString();
s.AppendChar('y');
s.AppendChar('o');
s.AppendChar('u');
s.AppendChar('r');
s.AppendChar('p');
s.AppendChar('a');
s.AppendChar('s');
s.AppendChar('s');
pi.Password = s;
pi.UseShellExecute = false; 
Process.Start(pi);
```

also to see the result of the command change the following two lines

```
pi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
pi.Arguments = "/k \"tscon.exe 0 /dest:console\"";
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, however i am getting exception ""The stub received bad data".
i verified that the user name and password are correct, i tried to put both USERNAME or DOMAIN\USERNAME. still not working

Comment: However I think this error comes from TSCON and perhaps is another problem. Try my second example without the paramenters `"/k \"tscon.exe /?\"";`

Comment: What does /dest:console do?

Answer (score 2):

While it looks like you found a workaround long ago, I have an explanation as to why the issue occurs and an arguably better solution. I ran into the same issue with shadow.exe.

If you watch with Process Monitor, you'll see that it's actually looking for the file in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ instead of C:\Windows\system32\ due to [File System Redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and your program being a 32-bit process.

The workaround is to compile for x64 instead of Any CPU or use P/Invoke to temporarily suspect and re-enable File System Redirection with the [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection Win API functions.

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);
}

////////////////

IntPtr wow64backup = IntPtr.Zero;
if (!Environment.Is64BitProcess && Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{                            
    NativeMethods.Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref wow64backup);
}

Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe", @"0 /dest:console"))

if (!Environment.Is64BitProcess && Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
    NativeMethods.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(wow64backup);
}
                        }
```