# cmd command msg not working

Tags: c#, cmd

It just says " 'msg' is not recognized as an internal or external program...."
I have searched a lot and still haven't found anything. Why doesn't it recognize it??

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strCmdText;       
        string user = textBox1.Text;
        string host = textBox2.Text;
        string time = textBox3.Text;
        string text = textBox4.Text;

        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You haven't specified a user!");
        }
        else if(textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You haven't specified the host!");
        }
        else if (textBox3.Text == "")
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You haven't specified the shutdown timer");
        }
        else
        {
            strCmdText = "/c msg " + user + "/server:" + host + " /time:" + time + " /w " + text;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `msg` is not part of your program path.

Comment: msg is an executable, why pass it to cmd?

Comment: msg is nothing.. msg.exe or msg.bat might be something.

Comment: verify msg file exist in your debug (or rel.) folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have 64bit machine. So try to specify full path to `msg.exe` `C:\Windows\Sysnative\msg.exe` or add `C:\Windows\Sysnative` to path variable .

[Source](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure "msg" command is working fine from the command line itself (CMD.exe).

If it is also providing the same error, make sure msg.exe exists in the System32 folder and the PATH environment variable has System32 folder path it.

The follwoing code seems fine, but did not work. It gave "msg.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command error.

```
 ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();            
 pi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 pi.Arguments = "/c msg.exe arguments";           
 pi.UseShellExecute = false;
 Process.Start(pi);
 Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

But setting the user information to the ProcessStartInfo, it worked and I was able to access the exe situated in System32 folder.

```
ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();            
pi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
pi.Arguments = "/c msg.exe arguments";
pi.UserName = "administrator";
System.Security.SecureString s = new System.Security.SecureString();
s.AppendChar('p');
s.AppendChar('a');
s.AppendChar('s');
s.AppendChar('s');
s.AppendChar('w');
s.AppendChar('o');
s.AppendChar('r');
s.AppendChar('d');
pi.Password = s;
pi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(pi);
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10932062/2382414

Comment: This can be posted in comments.